# How to properly sample around a textureCoordinate in texture2D in glsl

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I am wanting to sample 8 pixels around a specific pixel and calculate a bunch of information from this to use in a thresholding routine.

This is in iOS using a glsl vertex and fragment shaders.

Here is my sampling code from the fragment shader:

```
p00 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(-1.0*extent, -1.0*extent)); 
p01 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2( 0.0, -1.0*extent));
p02 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(+1.0*extent, -1.0*extent));
p10 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(-1.0*extent,  0.0));
p11 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);
p12 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(+1.0*extent,  0.0));
p20 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(-1.0*extent, +1.0*extent));
p21 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2( 0.0, +1.0*extent));
p22 = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate+vec2(+1.0*extent, +1.0*extent));
```

extent is just a number, currently set to 20.0.  I want the sampling to happen reasonably locally.

This compiles ok, however based on the results of my routines, I suspect that this is not sampling pixels around the current pixel, rather it seems to be sampling pixels extending along a row.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

The other reason I am not sure if this works is in the iOS documentation Apple states that this should be packaged in an image unit and that a regionofinterest function be used.  I would prefer to keep it all in the glsl shader if all possible.

Answer (score 0):

If extent is 20, you'll be sampling the 8 pixels that are in the 8 cardinal directions around the current one, but 20 pixels away. (So 20 pixels "north", 20 pixels "north east", etc.) If it's 1.0, then what you've written should sample the 8 pixels around the current pixel. (I'm also assuming that textureCoordinate is the current pixel's coordinate. Make sure that's the case.)

Comment: I should add - ImageUnits are different and you can't write your own ImageUnits on iOS (yet), so you can ignore that.

Comment: Hi - yes that was what I intended.  To sample the 20 pixels north, south, east, etc.   However, when running the shader on an iPhone, it seems to only sample pixels in a row and not a column.   Could this be something do do with the order in which the GPU processes pixels?

Comment: What are the texture coordinates of the object you're sampling from? If the texture coordinates Y values are the same, then I could see something like that happening.

Comment: The object I am sampling is a video frame from the iPhone camera.   It is 1920x1080.